# Which schema does this associative table belong to?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, associative-table

I was going over AdventureWorks2008 database and wanted to create a new table that associates a product to a sales person.

There is a many-to-many relationship between those tables.

[image]

The question is,
Of two schemas, `Sales` and `Production`, does `ProductSalesPerson` table belong to?
`ProductSalesPerson` doesn't neccessarily belong to either schema.

Should I create a new schema for this associative table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are Production and Sales are in different schemas?

On the assumption that they just are, and you can't change that -- put it in whatever schema is responsible for the bigger perspective share. Meaning, if your question is usually "who is responsible for selling product x?" -- it should go into Production.  If it's more of the "what product does salesperson x sell?" -- it should go into Sales.

This is kind of a screwy design imho, for the very reason of cross-schema relationships not having an obvious home (but if there are good reasons for setting things up this way, I would appreciate being enlightened).

Comment: (1) I'd guess it belongs in Sales, since it seems more an attribute/description of a salesperson than a product.

Comment: (2) Adventureworks is a sample database, designed to show of the myriad features of SQL Server 2005. As such, I'd have to guess "proper design" came second.

Comment: @SquareCog: "what product does salesperson x sell?" -- it should go into Sale  <-- That is what makes sense to me in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In real life there would be a user to ask.  But if we have to guess, it is normal for sales people to be assigned products as their beat, and the responsibility for that decision is taken by Sales rather than Product Development.  So I would say that your intersection should belong in SALES rather than PRODUCTION.